# How to randomly separte large data set into two equally sized data sets

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have several CSV files with 10 million+ values in them, each value is 9 characters long. My goal is to divide each file into two equally sized files, where each half is a random selection of the values from the initial set.

I am thinking about doing this using PHP (because I am slightly familiar with it).

I can think of two potential ways to do this, but curious about (1) which one will run faster? (2) is there a different way of doing that will be better? (3) or with a data set of about 10 to 15 million does it not matter?

Plan 1:

1. Convert CSV into an array
2. Shuffle the array using the shuffle() function
3. Divide the array in 2 with the array_chunk() function
4. Save each array to CSV file (not sure how but will figure it out)

Plan 2:

1. Convert CSV into an array
2. Use array_rand() to randomly select X amount of values, where X = (number of values / 2), and create array from that selection
3. Repeat step 2 for second half of values
4. Save each of the new arrays to CSV file

Is this anywhere close to right? Should I consider a different language?

Thank you!

Comment: If the files are that large, forget about using arrays (too high memory requirement).... create a temp database table, load the data into that and handle all randomisation through the database before writing back to file

Comment: Does your server have the memory to store 90 million characters in an array?

Comment: fastest/easiest way is via Linux shell commands   `wc -l file` to get #of lines and `split -l X file` where X is ~half what the wc command gave you. Lots of "split" examples, like this one...
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/split-a-text-file-in-half-or-any-percentage-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: @DuaneLortie - does that solve the "randomize" portion of the question?

Comment: The question is contradictory.. "separate large data set into two equally sized data sets"..  two equally sized data sets is not a random split

Comment: The body of the question pretty clearly states the random piece, but you are right - the title doesn't make it that clear.

Answer (score -1):

Plan 3:

1) Write a PHP script that fetches all CSV data and insert it to an MySQL database (plenty of exmples).

2) in your PHP `select * from table where type = 1 order by rand() limit 10` or some other fancy query with timestamp whatever

This is how I would do it.

EDIT with example

```
<?php

$files = glob("path/to/files/*.csv");

foreach($files as $file) {

    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        echo "<b>Filename: " . basename($file) . "</b><br><br>";
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            //do something with the data
            echo implode("\t", $data);
        }
        echo "<br>";
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        echo "Could not open file: " . $file;
    }
}

?>
```

This will get the content of all the csv files in a directory. Keep in mind this is a stressfull task for a server specially with so many values. So maybe this helps:

```
function listdirfile_by_date($path)
{
$dir = opendir($path);
$list = array();
while($file = readdir($dir))
{
    if($file != '..' && $file != '.')
    {
        $mtime = filemtime($path . $file) . ',' . $file;
        $list[$mtime] = $file;
    }
}
closedir($dir);
krsort($list);

foreach($list as $key => $value)
{
    return $list[$key];
}
return '';
}
```

A stolen function that lists the files sorted by date. With this data you can run the script only with the newest file.

Comment: I'd upvote, but it's fairly weak as an answer.  Would appreciate more completeness...

Comment: Yeah, adding more dependencies and technology will very likely make better solutions, and it will also be lightning fast. Especially for something that looks like a one-time operation.